# Lenovo laptop doesn't go beyond boot screen, can't enter BIOS menu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, laptop, partitioning

My Lenovo U510 was originally installed with Windows 8, and I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu alongside it, so I shrunk the existing Windows  volumes (there's an SSD and a HDD) slightly in order to make room for the new partition,

In hindsight, I probably should have done this while I wasn't half asleep, as now I don't completely remember everything I was doing. I know I shrunk partitions, installed Ubuntu onto manually created partitions, and then after else who knows what else I did to the poor laptop.

When I boot up the laptop, the Lenovo logo appears for a short while (can't go into BIOS/BootMenu anymore by pressing F2/F12 respectively), then the screen just has a blinking "_" at the top left corner and is unresponsive to any sort of input. Any idea what I can do to fix this? I'm pretty sure a majority of my data is there, as my Windows  partition was working fine until I restarted to boot back into Ubuntu and started getting this error.

Is there still anything I can still do with what I have, or should I just get someone else who actually knows what they're doing to help me deal with this huge mess I've made.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try removing your disk and booting. I would tinker with everything uefi related and try a bios update.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps to get into BIOS and restore default settings,

Perform a Power Drain

Remove the battery and Power cable

Press the power button for 5+ seconds to drain the leftout power

Now insert Battery, turn on the laptop and try hitting F1 to enter BIOS

Once access BIOS restore default settings and check whether the system successfully boot up or not.

If the above method fails,

Completely shutdown the notebook by holding down the power button for 5+ seconds.
Then, turn it back on and once you see the Lenovo logo for the first time, press enter then you'll get a menu of options, one being to enter the bios. Then restore default settings, save and exit.